# Locate the present address bar in Google Chrome (Auto IT)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, autoit

I am trying to Locate the address bar of the "Google Chrome". Can anybody help me on how can I send a value not a URL on the present address bar? I have tried to fix this problem by having this code:

`"Send ( "!dNike{ENTER}" )" or "Alt + D + value + Hit Enter"`.

But what I really need is to Locate the present address bar of Google Chrome and give a value like "Nike" for example.

I need to do this because Selenium WebDriver is only capable on sending "URL". I will really appreciate your help

Please see the attached picture for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take the window name by using the finder tool. Here we go!

```
WinWaitActive("New Tab - Google Chrome")
Send("Hello motto")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Sometimes even the Title is already present. It's not executing the code. Any idea bro?

Comment: What do you mean by title is not present. The same code works for me.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Ctrl+L to edit the address bar in a browser.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "l"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys("NIKE",Keys.ENTER);
```

I have tested this above in firefox and this works.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Santhosh, Good day!. I tried to use your code but it's giving me an error. I believe we can't do "2 sendkeys" like in your code. Is there another way around for this? I tried to use the "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"l"));" and it work fine. but it's giving me an error if I will sendKeys("NIKE")

Comment: Use Actions class for sendkeying NIKE. Have updated the answer

Comment: I'm really sorry bro. But it's not sending the value "NIKE" can you please try it on your end? I really appreciate your help. I just need this so badly because of my tight deadline and I don't know how to solve this :(

Comment: Can you paste the code that you have tried using mine's. I will check from that

Comment: It's just a simple: 

driver.get("https://google.com");
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "l"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys("NIKE");
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.close();